# Using dotnet from docker to power Visual Studio C# extension (OmniSharp)

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

I have recently tried to do some C# development on my Linux box with the help of the docker image microsoft/dotnet which works great within the docker image.

Yet I would like to use Visual Studio Code with the C# extension powered by OmniSharp to get intellisense/autocompletion, and the other benefits of that extension within that editor.

The problem is that .NET Core is not supported on my distribution (Arch). There is an AUR package but it has been more often broken than working and I would rather stick with my docker image to run dotnet in a container.

Hence my question is: can I make Visual Studio Code's C# extension which is running on my host OS use the dotnet tools available in the docker image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can hook your C# code in the container via **Docker Volumes**. Try something like this:

`docker run --name app -d -p 5000:5000 -v <your-project-path>:/app microsoft/dotnet`

*Note: Make sure that you are using the .NET Core SDK image.*

Comment: since I am have not .net sdk installed in my machine just using from docker container, Omnisharp is not working cause it doesn´t detect any installed .NET SDKs, even if i have volumes created for my project

Comment: I also have a similar problem, In my case I have the SDK installed on the host, but since it's not the same used to build the application (the app uses the docker container's sdk), omnisharp cannot find any references to the code and leaves everything with squiggly lines. I probably need to map the host sdk to the container, but I don't know which files are necessary.